# How can I check that spin_lock is working correctly?

Tags: c, linux, concurrency, linux-kernel, spinlock

I've implemented a basic Linux kernel module with /proc.

It can add elements to the linked list with `echo add number > /proc/list` and remove elements from the list with `echo remove number > /proc/list`. I've added `spin_lock` and `spin_unlock` around all critical sections (adding and removing elements elements from the list).

How can I check that the spinlocks are working correctly? I've tried making 2 scripts, one for adding elements and the other one for removing, and then executing them simultaneously with `./script1.sh & ./script2.sh`. But the result is the same with and without spinlocks.

Comment: **Concurrent** issues are always difficult to test and to debug. "How can I check that the spinlocks are working correctly?" - Because the critical section for spinlocks shouldn't be "too long" and shouldn't use waiting, in testing scenario you need to enter this section from several threads as many times as you can. The **more times** you enter the section from the different threads, the **more probability** of simultaneous entering you have.

Comment: Note also, that you need to create a test scenario in such way, that simultaneous entering (as if **without spinlocks**) could **actually** be **detectable**: cause a BUG triggered, a fault or other behavior you could caught.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to do it with more calls.